# How to return two OUT parameters from SQL Server using sp_executesql

Tags: sql-server

I want to return total amount and page count.

I want to return PageCount as int and TotalAmount as decimal

```
  @SQL = 'select cast (row_number() over( ORDER BY |SortedColumn| |SortedOrder| ) as int)NO , * into #table  From  (Select SPM.Id as Id,SPM.SalePrice As PlanAmount,SPM.CreatedDate as CreatedDate,SPM.ExpertId as ExpertUserProfileId,P.Id as PatientId,ISNULL((P.FirstName +'' '' + P.LastName),'''') as PatientName 
              from SubscribedPlanByMember SPM
                JOIN Patient P ON 
                P.UserProfileId=SPM.MemberId
                ) SP Where  1=1 '
         + @Where  +
         ' select @x =  CEILING(CAST((CAST(@@rowcount AS FLOAT)/ CAST('+ltrim(@PageSize)+' AS FLOAT)) AS FLOAT))
         select *  from #table as t where NO between '+ltrim(@PageIndex-@PageSize+1)+' and '+ltrim(@PageIndex)+'  '

    SET @TotalAmount= CAST(( select Sum(SalePrice) as Amount from SubscriptionPlanOfExperts where ExpertId=@UserProfileId) as decimal)

          SET @SQL= REPLACE(@SQL, '|SortedColumn|', @sortedColumn);
            SET @SQL= REPLACE(@SQL, '|SortedOrder|', @sortedOrder);
 print(@SQL)

 exec sp_executesql @SQL, N'@x int out', @PageCount out
```

Comment: Please include all relevant code in your example. Where are your variables defined and set?

Comment: Maybe do an INSERT INTO #TempTable EXEC(@SQL) with the output values you want returned as SELECTs from the dynamic block. Then do whatever with the 2x values once there in the #TempTable

Comment: You can return multiple output parameters from sp_executesql. See MSDN https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's perfectly acceptable to have multiple output parameters in a call to `sp_executesql`. See the following MS support article: https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/kb/262499.

This provides the following example of multiple output parameters:

```
DECLARE @SQLString NVARCHAR(500)
DECLARE @ParmDefinition NVARCHAR(500)
DECLARE @parmIN VARCHAR(10)
DECLARE @parmRET1 VARCHAR(30)
DECLARE @parmRET2 VARCHAR(30)
SET @parmIN=' returned'
SET @SQLString=N'EXEC Myproc @parm,
                             @parm1OUT OUTPUT, @parm2OUT OUTPUT'
SET @ParmDefinition=N'@parm varchar(10),
                      @parm1OUT varchar(30) OUTPUT,
                      @parm2OUT varchar(30) OUTPUT'

EXECUTE sp_executesql
    @SQLString,
    @ParmDefinition,
    @parm=@parmIN,
    @parm1OUT=@parmRET1 OUTPUT,@parm2OUT=@parmRET2 OUTPUT

SELECT @parmRET1 AS "parameter 1", @parmRET2 AS "parameter 2"
```

In your case, you simply need to amend your `sp_executesql` call to something like:

```
exec sp_executesql @SQL, N'@x int output, @TotalAmount decimal output', @PageCount=@x int output, @othervar=@TotalAmount decimal output
```